# Sorting List By Object Field

Tags: java, sorting

I'm getting a null pointer, not familiar with the compare methods and trying to figure out where I'm going wrong. The idea is I sort by the number of products sold and then get the top 5 products sold. It returns a NullPointer once I implement the compare methods.

```
public Result index() {
    // Get list of all categories in ascending order
    String name = "Best Sellers";
    List<Category> categoriesList = Category.findAll();
    List<Product> productsList;
    Long cat = new Long("11");
    productsList = bestSellers();

    return ok(index.render(env, categoriesList, productsList, cat, "", getCurrentUser(), name));
}


public List<Product> bestSellers(){
    List<Product> temp = Product.findAll("");
    Collections.sort(temp, new Comparator<Product>() {
         @Override
         public int compare(Product p1, Product p2) {
             if(p1.getCopiesSold()>p2.getCopiesSold()){
                return 1;
             } else if(p1.getCopiesSold()<p2.getCopiesSold()){
                 return -1;
             }
             return 0;
         }
    });

    List<Product> bestSellers = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        bestSellers.add(temp.get(i));
    }
    return bestSellers;
}
```

My getter was returning null for some items that have yet to have a purchase so I just had to add a check for null and everything works fine.

```
public Integer getCopiesSold() {
    if(copiesSold==null){
        copiesSold = 0;
    }
    return copiesSold;
}
```

Comment: can you post the error log?

Comment: also, what is this meant to do --> Product.findAll(""); ?

Comment: there is a mistake within your comparison as well, the else if is supposed to be --> else if(p1.getCopiesSold() < p2.getCopiesSold()). However that's not the cause of the null pointer I am sure.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw It just finds all the products, and the quotes are a filter for a search but I want to find all so I just leave blank. Oh, I didn't notice I forgot to change when I copied and pasted. I'm just trying to fix it now, will update with error log in a few minutes if I can't get it working.

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: in this code `for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        bestSellers.add(temp.get(i));
    }` how do you know that `temp` is or not `null` or that it has `five` elements?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Yes, the second case would, but not the first.  It does indicate sloppy coding though.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw I updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your method `findAll()`. It would appear that it is giving a list where some values have a value of null. When your compare method is called by the sorting algorithm used by `Collections`, `p1.getCopiesSold` or `p2.getCopiesSold` gives an error because p1 or p2 is null.

It is also possible that the method is `findAll()` is returning null and not a `List`, or that the method `getCopiesSold` returns null.

In java, something can have a value of null without throwing an exception, it only throws an exception when you try to call a method or preform an operation with it. Because of this, the null variable could be any of the variables being used by the line throwing the error.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed this within the getter but it's not giving me the top 5 products sold. I want to reverse the order of the list?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw I just updated it, that was the problem but I want to reverse the order of the List, I was looking at the reverse API call. Is it similar?

Comment: @Lee use Collections.Reverse() method